# Remote Desktop - Not Working From One Network to Another

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Ok...this is the weirdest thing I've ever seen. I have an employee that is using her personal laptop to access her work desktop via VPN and Remote Desktop to where she'll VPN into the company network then open Remote Desktop to run her workstation. Now the thing is, I tested all of this using her laptop on my network (not the company network) and everything worked. We were able to VPN into the company network, open remote desktop and control her workstation.

Now she's gone home and is attempting to connect to her workstation. She can VPN into the company network, but when she attempts to control her workstation using remote desktop she says she gets an error message saying "cannot connect to remote computer".

This is extremely frustrating because I can connect via VPN and remote desktop into her workstation from my home network, but she can't from hers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Her network provider probably blocks GRE.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Port 3389 for rdp needs to be open as well I would add an exception on the laptop that she is using

Comment: Most new ADSL modems block all traffic other than your basic internet protocols.  Most also have a _relatively_ trivial way of enabling remote desktop. Not necessarily going to be an easy thing to talk her through though.